# Why does Math.log10 work on some systems but return undefined on others?

Tags: javascript

I wrote an html5 canvas based app for plotting the electric potential as a color-map. I was using Math.log10 to re-scale the values and this worked well on quite a few systems (Chrome-Firefox-Opera; laptops and PC; Windows and Ubuntu; integrated and dedicate graphics). And then I found one PC and one laptop both with Windows where the plot would not work. The error was showing that Math.log10() could not be called as a function and just typing Math.log10 in the js console returned undefined. I got around this glitch by replacing Math.log10(someValue) with Math.log(someValue)/2.3.
So my questions are: why does this happens and are there any other similar annoying differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is browser-specific. Not all browsers support the experimental `Math.log10()` function - the main one being Internet Explorer.

`Math.log()` however is a separate function which was introduced long before `Math.log10()`, and has much greater browser support.

The Mozilla Developer Network lists [browser support for `Math.log10()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10):

> #### Desktop Browsers
>
> ```
> Chrome    Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
> 38        25 (25)         Not supported       25      7.1
> ```
>
> #### Mobile Browsers
>
> ```
> Android         Chrome for Android    Firefox Mobile (Gecko)  IE Mobile      Opera Mobile    Safari Mobile
> Not supported   Not supported         25.0 (25)               Not supported  Not supported   iOS 8
> ```

Comment: MDN also has the polyfill: `Math.log10 = function (x) { return Math.log(x) / Math.LN10; };`

Answer (score 14):

```
Math.log10 = Math.log10 || function(x) {
  return Math.log(x) * Math.LOG10E;
};
```

Paste this in your common JS file and this will resolve the issue if **log10** will not be supported by browser.

I know it is too late, but it might help if someone will reach your post while searching.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.log()` is the Napierian logarithm (ln).

So you should use `Math.log(value)/Math.log(10)`
since log<sub>10</sub>(X) = ln(X)/ln(10)

and `Math.log()` has much greater browser support as stated in [the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296928/why-does-math-log10-work-on-some-systems-but-return-undefined-on-others#28296971).