# Math.log10 is undefined/available in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, math, phantomjs

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Math.log10(10)')
```

How to solve this problem if I can't change the source code of the project?

I can change the code of the PhantomJS script.

This question can be anwsered in part by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296928). The difference is how is the proper way of injecting the solution into your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Math.log10 work on some systems but return undefined on others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296928/why-does-math-log10-work-on-some-systems-but-return-undefined-on-others)

Comment: Specifically check out the comment about the polyfill

Comment: polyfill solution is good, but it is not complete. The accepted answer gives a crucial piece of information that is determinant to succed: _"This is done by registering to the page.onInitialized event handler:"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page needs this function, you can easily add it. Use for example the [polyfill as provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10).

The polyfill must be applied as early as possible. This is done by registering to the [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) event handler:

```
page.onInitialized = function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        Math.log10 = Math.log10 || function(x) {
            return Math.log(x) / Math.LN10;
        };
    });
};
```

This works in all PhantomJS versions.